# PhoneGap unable to connect to localhost php file using ajax

Tags: phonegap

I'm trying to develop a login app using PhoneGap. I am able to connect to the php file using ajax through the browser but I can't connect through the PhoneGap app on my phone.

I've tried white listing it in the config.xml using

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
```

And also

```
    <access origin="http://192.168.7.113/FirstApp/apiservice/fetchdata.php" subdomains="true"/>
```

But it did not work.

Additionally I added the access control allow origin to the php

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

And I added the Content Security policy to the html file

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

If you guys could please help me. I'd really appreciate a working example. I've tried everything.

Comment: You can use <access origin="*" /> to allows access to any external resource.

Comment: I used that but still not connecting to the device